# What are a few examples of unexplained physics phenomena we encounter in our everyday lives?

Tags: everyday-life

Are there still everyday phenomena unexplained by Physics?
If yes, what are a few?

Comment: "Explained" at what level? Explain "why" vs "how"?

Comment: Some comments removed. To post a brief answer, post an answer. To answer a closed question, vote to reopen. Consider [this discussion about "list questions"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10457/44126) when voting.

Comment: @JonCuster I need a 'how' explanation

Comment: Lots. Chemistry is based on physics. But most of chemistry is not explained in directly terms of physics (quantum mechanics) because it would be hard. Likely to hard to calculate. Laws of chemistry are a shortcut. Likewise, biology is based on chemistry, but has its own rules. Someday we may be able to explain conciousness in terms of biology like we can now explain life. But physics has no way to even start on it.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the Mpemba effect is one of those unexplained phenomena, although it is not really an everyday phenomenon. It seems to be trivial thermodynamics but there is no accepted explanation yet.
[Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpemba_effect)